# Is it possible for Fargate task (container) to retrieve its metadata, e.g. service name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

Let's say certain docker image is to be deployed on different service name within a cluster.  I think this can happen if you want a sophisticated deployment which results in not only one uniform workers of that image.

In such case, I'd want the task itself to recognize in which service name that task is being executed.
In EC2, as far as I understand, some metadata about the instance can be obtained by accessing `169.254.169.254`, as described in their doc. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

## Question

- Is there any way for a Fargate Task to obtain it's metadata from AWS?

  - Namely, I want to know the service name of Fargate cluster.  Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html. But, I guess, this may not provide the ECS-Service Info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use version [task-metadata-endpoint-v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3.html)

```
curl ${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI}/task
```

This path returns metadata JSON for the task, including a list of the **container IDs and names** for all of the containers associated with the task. For more information about the response for this endpoint, see [Task Metadata JSON Response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v3.html).

**Amazon ECS Task Metadata Endpoint**

The Amazon ECS container agent provides a method to retrieve various task metadata and Docker stats. This is referred to as the task metadata endpoint. The following versions are available:

Task metadata endpoint version 3 – Available for tasks that use the Fargate launch type on platform version v1.3.0 or later and tasks that use the EC2 launch type and are launched on Amazon EC2 infrastructure running at least version 1.21.0 of the Amazon ECS container agent. For more information, see Task Metadata Endpoint version 3.

Comment: can you please help out here ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105216/how-to-get-metadata-for-aws-fargate-platform-v1-3-0